# error en recorrido de fila de un reader() dentro de otro reader()

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net

Tengo este método donde intento colocar un `while read()` dentro de otro con diferente nombre de comando para recuperar datos de mi BD, pero me genera un error que dice

> {"Ya hay un DataReader abierto asociado a este Command, debe cerrarlo primero."}

¿Está correcto mi método o tengo que cambiar algo ya que no puedo ejecutar un comando `Read()` dentro de otro?

```
public List<entConfiguracion> MuestraConfiguracionPredeterminada()
{
    int ValorId = 0;

    IDataParameter[] prms = new IDataParameter[]
    {
                new SqlParameter(){ParameterName="@Predeterminado",SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Bit,Value=1},
                new SqlParameter(){ParameterName="@Activo",SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Int,Value=1},
    };

    IDataReader drConfig = DB.EjecutarReaderSP("SP_ObtenerConfiguracionPredeterminada", prms);

    List<entConfiguracion> LstObtenerConfiguracion = new List<entConfiguracion>();

    while (drConfig.Read())
    {
        entConfiguracion obtener = new entConfiguracion();

        obtener.IdConfiguracion = Convert.ToInt32(drConfig["IdConfiguracion"]);
        obtener.NombreConfiguracion = drConfig["NombreConfiguracion"].ToString();
        obtener.NombreLicitacion = drConfig["NombreLic"].ToString();
        obtener.IdFormula = Convert.ToInt32(drConfig["IdFormula"]);
        ValorId = obtener.IdFormula;
        /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        IDataParameter[] prms1 = new IDataParameter[]
        {
                new SqlParameter(){ParameterName="@IdFormula",SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Int,Value=ValorId},
        };

        IDataReader drConfig1 = DB.EjecutarReaderSP("SP_GetVariablesCheck", prms1);

        while (drConfig1.Read())
        {
            obtener.IdVariable = Convert.ToInt16(drConfig1["IdVariable"]);
            LstObtenerConfiguracion.Add(obtener);
        }
        drConfig1.Close();
        drConfig1.Dispose();
        /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
        obtener.TipoFuente = drConfig["TipoFuente"].ToString();
        obtener.TamanoFuente = Convert.ToInt32(drConfig["TamanoFuente"]);

        LstObtenerConfiguracion.Add(obtener);
    }
    drConfig.Close();
    drConfig.Dispose();

    return LstObtenerConfiguracion;
}
```

Comment: Tenes que hacer, exactamente lo que dice el error. es un reader por command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes crear mas de 1 DataReader a la vez. Tendras que terminar con uno y luego crear otro para hacer lo que deseas.

Por ejemplo pudieras cargar la lista de configuraciones, cerrar el reader y luego buscar las variables de las configuraciones:
int ValorId = 0;

```
IDataParameter[] prms = new IDataParameter[]
{
            new SqlParameter(){ParameterName="@Predeterminado",SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Bit,Value=1},
            new SqlParameter(){ParameterName="@Activo",SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Int,Value=1},
};

IDataReader drConfig = DB.EjecutarReaderSP("SP_ObtenerConfiguracionPredeterminada", prms);

List<entConfiguracion> LstObtenerConfiguracion = new List<entConfiguracion>();

while (drConfig.Read())
{
    // cargas las configuraciones
    entConfiguracion obtener = new entConfiguracion();

    obtener.IdConfiguracion = Convert.ToInt32(drConfig["IdConfiguracion"]);
    obtener.NombreConfiguracion = drConfig["NombreConfiguracion"].ToString();
    obtener.NombreLicitacion = drConfig["NombreLic"].ToString();
    obtener.IdFormula = Convert.ToInt32(drConfig["IdFormula"]);
    ValorId = obtener.IdFormula;

    /*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    obtener.TipoFuente = drConfig["TipoFuente"].ToString();
    obtener.TamanoFuente = Convert.ToInt32(drConfig["TamanoFuente"]);

    LstObtenerConfiguracion.Add(obtener);
}

// ciera el DataReader
drConfig.Dispose();

foreach(var configuracion in LstObtenerConfiguracion)
{
   // Ahora por cada conf buscas las variables abriendo otro data reader por conf
    IDataParameter[] prms1 = new IDataParameter[]
    {
            new SqlParameter(){ParameterName="@IdFormula",SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Int,Value=configuracion.FormulaId},
    };

    IDataReader drConfig1 = DB.EjecutarReaderSP("SP_GetVariablesCheck", prms1);

    while (drConfig1.Read())
    {
        configuracion.IdVariable = Convert.ToInt16(drConfig1["IdVariable"]);
        LstObtenerConfiguracion.Add(configuracion);
    }

    // cieras el data reader para crear otro luego
    drConfig1.Dispose();  
}

return LstObtenerConfiguracion;
```